# Doctrine prepare->execute

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-2

Olá, estou fazendo essa consulta com o Doctrine

```
$retorno = $em->getConnection()->prepare("
        SELECT
        t.id_programa_fidelidade_diario,
        t.loja,
        t.nota,
        t.data,
        t.ecf,
        t.operador,
        o.nome,
        programa_fidelidade_calculo_status(t.id)
        AS calculo_status,
        programa_fidelidade_calculo_valor(t.loja, t.Nota, t.Ecf, t.Data)
        AS calculo_bonus_valor
        FROM sef s,
        totcupom t
        LEFT JOIN operador o
        ON (t.operador=o.codigo)
        WHERE (t.loja=s.id)
        AND (t.data BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-30') LIMIT 1")->execute();
```

Porém o execute me retorna apenas um bool, e eu preciso que me retorne o resultado da consulta.Como posso faze-lo?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando o `prepare` do PDO ([porque Doctrine é feito com PDO](https://blog.schoolofnet.com/2015/04/substituindo-o-pdo-por-doctrine-dbal/)), então faça essas modificações no seu código:

```
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare("
        SELECT
        t.id_programa_fidelidade_diario,
        t.loja,
        t.nota,
        t.data,
        t.ecf,
        t.operador,
        o.nome,
        programa_fidelidade_calculo_status(t.id)
        AS calculo_status,
        programa_fidelidade_calculo_valor(t.loja, t.Nota, t.Ecf, t.Data)
        AS calculo_bonus_valor
        FROM sef s,
        totcupom t
        LEFT JOIN operador o
        ON (t.operador=o.codigo)
        WHERE (t.loja=s.id)
        AND (t.data BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-30') LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(); // ou ->fetch();
```

*isso seria o que você precisa no seu código, mas, como não tem parametro, será que precisa preparar essa* `SQL`?

***Poderia simplificar:***

```
$results = $em->getConnection()->query("
        SELECT
        t.id_programa_fidelidade_diario,
        t.loja,
        t.nota,
        t.data,
        t.ecf,
        t.operador,
        o.nome,
        programa_fidelidade_calculo_status(t.id)
        AS calculo_status,
        programa_fidelidade_calculo_valor(t.loja, t.Nota, t.Ecf, t.Data)
        AS calculo_bonus_valor
        FROM sef s,
        totcupom t
        LEFT JOIN operador o
        ON (t.operador=o.codigo)
        WHERE (t.loja=s.id)
        AND (t.data BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-30') LIMIT 1")
->fetchAll(); // ou ->fetch();
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Substituindo o PDO por Doctrine DBAL](https://blog.schoolofnet.com/2015/04/substituindo-o-pdo-por-doctrine-dbal/)
- [Simplifying database interactions with Doctrine DBAL](https://www.thedevfiles.com/2014/08/simplifying-database-interactions-with-doctrine-dbal/)

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Funcionou certinho.
Sobre não ter parâmetro.. vai ter, é que eu estava testando o Doctrine sem os paramêtros antes, já que não tenho muita prática .